# How do I get inner value in HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable T

T =  < input type="text" name="amount" value="3"  class="txt-spin" />

Question : How do I get "3" in this tag using javascript ..?

Comment: it'd be `T.value` - if `T` refers to the **actual** HTML element

Comment: @DarrenChand, the requirement is to get an attribute not a tag

Comment: replace with getAttribute()

Comment: First, your question is not clear at all. So try to edit and describe properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong in the way you're associating the HTML element to a JS Variable.

BUT

If you are using js for this: you can use `.getAttribute()` [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)

Useful:
[How to work with HTML elements in JS](https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties)

Answer (score 0):

T = document.getElementByClassName("txt-spin").value